# If the mean of $x,y,z$ is $3x$, what is the mean of $y$ and $z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $x, y, z$ are three numbers. The mean of $x, y, z$ is $3x$. What is the mean of $y$ and $z$?

Is the answer $4x$?

Comment: If $\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}=3x$, then...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Simply write: 
$$
\frac{x+y+z}{3} = 3x\Rightarrow y+z = 8x\Rightarrow \frac{y+z}{2} = 4x.
$$

Answer (score 4):

If the mean of three numbers is $3x$, then the sum of the numbers is $9x$. ...

Comment: This answer is useful.